# PHPExcel - Call to a member function getCacheData() on null

Tags: php, phpexcel, cakephp-3.1

I am getting an error something like below when writing a file

```
Error: Call to a member function getCacheData() on null 
File E:\websites\d3a-qa\vendor\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php 
Line: 2554
```

**Line 2554:**

```
public function garbageCollect() {
        // Flush cache
        $this->_cellCollection->getCacheData('A1');
```

I know this error is coming because `$this->_cellCollection` is `null` but I dont know why is it `null`. I am calling `$writer->save($saving_name);` where it gives this issue.

I tried doing all sort of things. From backtracing to commenting the disconnectWorksheet code. resetting the variables for PHPExcel object but nothing works.

The funny part is sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. There's not much documentation or answers to queries aboout PHPExcel on internet. Therefore at last I have come here so that I could get any answer or at least a hint of what needs to be done.

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT**

Here's my code where I am using PHPExcel. It appears that the error is coming at `$writer->save($saving_name);`.

`$parts` is an array having several number of XLS that needs to be merged into one XLS sheet.

PS: The error comes only when heavy processing is done (or nearly 45 sheets). For smaller xls counts its working fine.

```
if(!empty($insertSummary)) {
            $PHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
            $PHPExcel = $PHPExcel->createSheet();
            $PHPExcel->setTitle(_EXPORT_DES_SUMMARY);
        }

        foreach ($parts as $part) {        
            $bigExcel = '';

            if(!empty($insertSummary))
                $bigExcel = $this->addSummarySheet($insertSummary, $part, $PHPExcel);

            $bigExcel = $this->processPartFiles($part, $bigExcel);

            $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($bigExcel, 'Excel5');
            $returnFilename = $dbName . '_' . 'DES' . '_' . date('Y-m-d-h-i-s') . '_' . 'Part_' . ++$count . '.xls';

            // name of file, which needs to be attached during email sending
            $saving_name = _DES_PATH_WEBROOT . DS . $returnFilename;

            $zipFiles[] = $saving_name;
            $writer->save($saving_name);

            //Log::write('debug', 'Line(' . __LINE__ .') memory_get_peak_usage - ' . memory_get_peak_usage(true));
            //Log::write('debug', 'Line(' . __LINE__ .') memory_get_usage - ' . memory_get_usage());
        }
```

**EDIT-2**

**$this->addSummarySheet()**

```
public function addSummarySheet($insertSummary, $part, $PHPExcel) {
        $keys = array_keys($part);
        $bigExcel = $this->CommonInterface->readXlsOrCsv($insertSummary, false);

        //Copy & paste values of range of cells
        $cellValuesTitle = $bigExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:C1');
        $cellValues = $bigExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A' . ($keys[0] + 1) .':C' . ($keys[count($keys) - 1] + 1));
        $bigExcel->removeSheetByIndex(0);

        $bigExcel->addSheet($PHPExcel);
        $bigExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cellValuesTitle, null, 'A1');
        $bigExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cellValues, null, 'A2');

        foreach($keys as $rowCount => $sheet) {
            $cellCordinateRow = $rowCount + 2;
            $bigExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' . $cellCordinateRow)->getHyperlink()->setUrl("sheet://'Data $sheet'!A{$cellCordinateRow}");
        }

        return $bigExcel;
    }
```

**$this->CommonInterface->readXlsOrCsv()**

```
public function readXlsOrCsv($filename = null, $unlinkFile = true, $sheetnames = null) {

        require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'PHPExcel' . DS . 'PHPExcel' . DS . 'IOFactory.php');
        /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
        $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

        if(!empty($sheetnames)) {
            //$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
            $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames);
        }
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);

        //$objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
        if ($unlinkFile == true)
            $this->unlinkFiles($filename); // Delete The uploaded file
        return $objPHPExcel;
    }
```

Comment: This hapless developer abases himself for not providing sufficient documentation (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation and http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/) about his useless product, and apologises for never answering queries (http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bphpexcel%5d%20user%3a324584) but perhaps showing a little bit more of your code, or at least telling me what version of PHPExcel you're running, might allow me to at least attempt to guess what is going wrong

Comment: @MarkBaker I am using v1.8.0.  I will edit the Ques with the code where I am using it.

Comment: Can you show the code for `$this->addSummarySheet();`?

Comment: I have added the code in question under `EDIT-2` for `addSummarySheet()` and `readXlsOrCsv()`.

Comment: @MarkBaker. You are in the right direction as when I comment the `$this->addSummarySheet()` the code works fine for larger files as well. The issue is with the `$this->addSummarySheet()` function. I am focusing on debugging this function now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue I was facing with PHPExcel.

I have changed removed `$bigExcel = $this->CommonInterface->readXlsOrCsv($insertSummary, false);` from `$this->addSummarySheet()` and placed it under `if(!empty($insertSummary)) {` as stated in **EDIT 2**.

Also, I have added below line of code in `$this->addSummarySheet()`

```
$PHPExcelSheet = new \PHPExcel();
$PHPExcelSheet->removeSheetByIndex(0);

$PHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
$PHPExcel = $PHPExcel->createSheet();
$PHPExcel->setTitle(_EXPORT_DES_SUMMARY);
```

SO My final code in `$this->addSummarySheet()` becomes

```
public function addSummarySheet($insertSummary, $part, $PHPExcel, $summaryExcel) {
        $keys = array_keys($part);
        //$summaryExcel= $this->CommonInterface->readXlsOrCsv($insertSummary, false);

        //Copy & paste values of range of cells
        $cellValuesTitle = $summaryExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:C1');
        $cellValues = $summaryExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A' . ($keys[0] + 1) .':C' . ($keys[count($keys) - 1] + 1));

        $PHPExcelSheet = new \PHPExcel();
        $PHPExcelSheet->removeSheetByIndex(0);

        $PHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
        $PHPExcel = $PHPExcel->createSheet();
        $PHPExcel->setTitle(_EXPORT_DES_SUMMARY);

        $PHPExcelSheet->addSheet($PHPExcel);
        $PHPExcelSheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cellValuesTitle, null, 'A1');
        $PHPExcelSheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cellValues, null, 'A2');

        foreach($keys as $rowCount => $sheet) {
            $cellCordinateRow = $rowCount + 2;
            $PHPExcelSheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' . $cellCordinateRow)->getHyperlink()->setUrl("sheet://'Data $sheet'!A{$cellCordinateRow}");
        }

        return $PHPExcelSheet;
    }
```

Thanks Mark for providing the `$this->addSummarySheet()` hint. It truly helped.

Comment: I'm not sure that I did much, besides seeing that the potential errors might lie in that method; but I'm glad you were able to resolve it